# Netlab graddesc function

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Does anyone know about [`graddesc`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2654-netlab/content/graddesc.m) function in the Netlab toolbox on the MATLAB File Exchange?

How does one use it?

```
graddesc(F, X, OPTIONS, GRADF, P1, P2, ...)
```

As I understand it, `F`, is your function. What is `X`? The domain of `F`? If so, then how would I incorporate the domain of a function of two variables? Options appears to be a vector that you create with the settings for the `graddesc` function. `GRADF` is a gradient of function `F` I suppose? If so, how do I incorporate a partial derivatives of a function w.r.t. the two variables? and `P1` and `P2` I assume is the guess point?

Comment: I'd think `x` is probably your initial guess, gradf(x) the gradient of f at point x (which contain all your partial derivatives)

Comment: P1, P2,P3,... are optional additional parameters that are passed to f and gradf

Comment: actually look at the doc it's very well explained: I assume that this function: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2654-netlab/content/graddesc.m

Comment: looked at the doc, i must be passing wrong inputs